# Retention of emails outside of Outlook

Tags: windows, exchange

If a user drags an email from Outlook to their desktop or into a Word document, does it become an independent object, or is it still "linked" back to Outlook/Exchange somehow? The professional context of this is: retention policies and enforcement.

Comment: It becomes an independent object (a .msg file) outside of Exchange.

Comment: By "retention and enforcement", do you mean you want to keep email data within Exchange and prevent leakage to local files?  Or do you mean you want to ensure all data is in Exchange, a la journaling?  I think Hopeless nailed it in his answer, but "Retention" can mean different things to different people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It becomes its own file.

Regarding retention and enforcement, the way I've always seen it done, in places where people actually cared, is to use folder redirection so that users can't save to their local hard disk, and then scan/search the file server where the folders are redirected to for `.pst` and `.msg` files.

Alternately, you can set up a file screen to outright block these types of files, but then you end up with users pasting their emails into Word or Notepad or whatever, which to be fair, isn't really something you can prevent anyway.